# TTImageView in TTTableViewCell cell reuse issue

Tags: iphone, ipad, three20, uitableview

Let me describe the issue that I am having using a video link [here](http://www.screenr.com/55Ns)

The issue is that the TTImageView, which is the avatar on the left is missing some image.
I believe this is because of cell reuse? How do I fix this?
Here is my code:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString*)identifier {
    if (self == [super initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue2 reuseIdentifier:identifier]) {
        _avatar = [[TTImageView alloc] init];
        [self.contentView addSubview:_avatar];

        _main_title = [[TTStyledTextLabel alloc] init];
        [self.contentView addSubview:_main_title];

        _detailed = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        [self.contentView addSubview:_detailed];

    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three20 has some issues with prepareForReuse function in the table cells. see https://github.com/facebook/three20/issues/497 for example.

What you can do now, to create a table item cell subclass of your own and have a prepareForReuse function.

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
- (void)prepareForReuse {
  [super prepareForReuse];

  [_imageView2 unsetImage];
}
```

I actually found that it's easier to use my own TTImageView, and not to use the existing _imageView TTImageView

Comment: also I don't think that it has to do with cell reuse, because when initially launched you can see there is some missing TTImageView... at that point it's not reusing anything